# APIキー(トークン)を含むプログラムのソースコード公開について

Tags: android, oauth

現在、TwitterやLast.fmにメッセージを送信するAndroidアプリを開発していますが、アプリには各サイトから取得したAPIキー(トークン)が含まれています。

もしこれらのアプリのソースコードを公開したいと思った場合、APIキーはどのように取り扱うのが一般的なのでしょうか？
特定のソースコードだけ切り離してビルドできない状態で公開するのはおかしいでしょうか？

また、こうしたAPIキーを他者に参照された場合、どのようなリスクがありますか？
(APKファイルを展開して参照されるリスクに対して、どこまで備える必要があるでしょうか？)

もしよろしければ、ご意見等お聞かせいただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> こうしたAPIキーを他者に参照された場合、どのようなリスクがありますか？

APIキーを手に入れた他者が、あなたに成りすましてAPIを呼び出すことができてしまいます。

その結果考えられる問題としては

- あなたのアプリしかアクセスできないはずの情報にアクセスされる
- 他者がそのAPIキーで悪事を働いた場合、あなたのアプリが悪さをしたと思われる
- あなたのアプリと関係のないところで多数の呼び出しが行われることで、APIの呼び出し回数制限や従量課金に引っかかる

などが挙げられますが、実際にはそのAPIキーで何ができるのか次第です。

例えば Twitter の Consumer Token で言えば、これ単体を盗んでできることはそのアプリに成りすまして悪事を働いて風評被害を狙うぐらいでしょう。しかしユーザーごとの Access Token まで盗むことができれば、ユーザーのDMを読み取ったり、ユーザーに成りすまして広告ツイートやDMを送ることができてしまいます。

というところで、Consumer Token よりユーザーごとの Access Token の管理の方が重要ですし、それがしっかりできていれば Consumer Token については妥協してもいいかなと思います。オープンソースのTwitterクライアントだと普通に平文でGithubに上げてたりしますし。

[security - Should I obfuscate OAuth consumer secret stored by Android app? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7121966/2818869)

Comment: アプリに成り済ます程度については妥協してしまうということですね。リンク先も大変参考になりました。さほど重要なアプリではないため、妥協してしまうことも検討してみます。

Answer (score 1):

ビルドできない状態で公開するのは、ビルドできない理由とその解消方法を別途解説する必要が出てきますし、個人的には不親切に感じます。

一般的かどうかはわかりませんが、APIキーのみを定義したxmlファイルをリソースとし、プログラム側で参照する方法は如何でしょうか。
　この場合、対象のxmlファイルは公開せず(リポジトリに含めず)、リソースが存在しない時にはダミーのAPIキーを用いるロジックを実装する事で、APIキーを非公開としながらもビルドが通る環境を公開できると考えます。

Comment: リソースの存在によって処理を切り替える感じですね。
ただAndroidのAPKファイルの場合、簡単に展開して内部のリソースを参照できてしまうため、どのようにキーを管理・保持するかが今一つよく分かりませんでした。
難読化したソースコードに含めてしまうのが良いのではないかと思ったのですが、そうなるとコードが欠けてしまうとビルドが通らず…という感じで悩んでいます。

Comment: なるほど。勘違いしていました。でも難読化は暗号化ではないのでソースコードに含めてもリソースにしたのと同じように読めてしまいますね。

Comment: 結局のところ、プログラム内にキーを保持する以上、キーがどの程度参照されにくい状態にあるかという差にしかならないのかな、と考えます。他者から気軽に利用されない程度に見にくくする、辺りで割り切ってしまうのが妥協点でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

APIキーをソースコードの中で使うべきではありません。

APIキーは、ユーザを特定し、そのユーザに課金したり、利用回数制限したりする目的で使われます。
そのようなキーを他人に知られた場合、自分で利用していない分の料金を払ったり、回数制限で利用できなくなったりといった不利益を被る可能性があります。

Comment: Androidのアプリ場合、プログラムはAPKファイル単体で構成されるため、どうしてもこの中にキーを含めざるを得なくなると考えています。ただ、APKファイルは簡単に展開できて内部が参照できてしまうため、どのようにキーを保存・管理するべきかが今一つ分からず、今回ような質問をさせていただきました。
外部からキーを安全に取得する良い手段があれば良いのですが、残念ながら思いつきませんでした…。